# Iterating results from execute results in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find a way to loop through each of the results from using the sql execute. I'm using the 'for' loop but it bunches all the values into one cell. I need to separate each value

So my table would have:
row1 = 1, 2, 3
row2 = a, b, c

Currently using this returns the values into one table cell:

```
<% for values in @results %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= values %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is how it shows

```
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>abc</td>
</tr>
```

How do I make it like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing `123` is because the array `[1, 2, 3]` is being printed, and (in Ruby 1.8) arrays are squished together when printed.

To print each individual value in a table cell, just use an inner for loop:

```
<% for values in @results %>
  <tr>
    <% for value in values %>
      <td><%= value %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Would you know how I would loop through each column name?